# How to create user with automatic default fields

Tags: django, model

I am not sure how to phrase this but I have the `User` from the user model given by `django.contrib.auth.models`

I can register, login, and logout a user but now I would like to do a bit more.

I want to have a wallet that the user is associated with upon registering. So far what I did was create a separate app called `wallets` and my model looks like...

```
class Wallet(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cash = models.FloatField(default=100, blank=True)
```

The idea is that instead of extending my User model class to have another field being that I am using the existing User model already I am doing a `OneToOneField(User)` so that a user is associated with a wallet and that wallet containing the default amount of cash of 100 dollars

When I create a user I want the wallet to be created and linked to that user as well. How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `post_save` signal that is triggered when a new user object is constructed:

```
# app/signals.py

from django.conf import settings
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver

@receiver(post_save, sender=settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
def create_wallet(sender, instance, created, *args, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Wallet.objects.create(user=instance)
```

You need to load the `signals` module. This can be done in the `AppConfig` of your app:

```
# app/apps.py

from django.apps import AppConfig

class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):
    name = 'app'

    def ready(self):
        import app.signals
```

and you configure the app in the `__init__.py` file:

```
# app/__init__.py

default_app_config = 'app.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Of course you need to replace the *`app`* part in the files with the name of the Django app.

---

> **Note**: It is normally better to make use of the [**`settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-AUTH_USER_MODEL) to refer to the user model, than to use the [**`User`** model [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User) directly. For more information you can see the [*referencing the `User` model* section of the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/customizing/#referencing-the-user-model).